# NullPointerException when trying to access database inside DialogInterface.OnClickListener of ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, sql, android-alertdialog

I have an expandable list adapter with categories and items under each category. If I click to delete an item, an alert dialog will pop up confirming deletion. When I press `yes` the debugger always stops at `dbHelper.deleteItemizedSpending` with a `NullPointerException`. I set a breakpoint inside `deleteItemizedSpending` but it does not enter the fn.

The database has already been initialized and opened for write in the main activity. I also checked the parameters `group.category_name`, `children.row_id`, `children.item_amount` are all valid. What's the problem here?

File ExpandableCategoryListAdapter.java (copied only relevant code):

```
public class ExpandableCategoryListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private DbHelper dbHelper; 

public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final Children children = (Children) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
// get a hold of layout elements
if (convertView == null) {
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
}
TextView tag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCategoryItemTag);
TextView amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCategoryItemAmount);
ImageView edit = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editCategoryItem);
ImageView delete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteCategoryItem);
tag.setText(children.tag_name);
amount.setText(Integer.toString(children.item_amount));

// method to handle edit item icon click

// method to handle delete item icon click
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {        
public void onClick(View v) {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
builder.setMessage("Delete?");
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
dbHelper.deleteItemizedSpending(group.category_name, children.row_id, 
children.item_amount);                                                 
// then remove row from dataset and notify that it changed
List<Children> child = groups.get(groupPosition).children;
child.remove(childPosition);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
});
```

File DbHelper.java (copied only relevant code):

```
public class DbHelper {
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Database dbHelper;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
this.context = context;
dbHelper = new Database(this.context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void deleteItemizedSpending(String table, long id, int amount) {
int travel_id = fetchTravelId(table, id, amount);

try {db.delete(
table, 
DatabaseContract.CategoryTable._ID + "=?" + " AND " +
DatabaseContract.CategoryTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT + "=?",
new String[] {String.valueOf(id), String.valueOf(amount)});}
catch (Exception e)
{
Log.e("DB ERROR 3", e.toString());
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

StackTrace:

> DalvikVM[localhost:8603]
>       Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))
>           ExpandableCategoryListAdapter$1$1.onClick(DialogInterface, int) line: 70
>           AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(Message) line: 167
>           AlertController$ButtonHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99
>           Looper.loop() line: 137 
>           ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4950
>           Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
>           Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511
>           ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1004 
>           ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 771 
>           NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
>       Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)
>       Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
>       Thread [<11> Binder_3] (Running)

Comment: I am not an expert but u r saying its only don't work here try: ExpandableCategoryListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged() instead

Answer (score 0):

The variable dbHelper is not initialized...

```
private DbHelper dbHelper;
```

This line crashes

```
dbHelper.deleteItemizedSpending(group.category_name, children.row_id, children.item_amount);
```

Comment: Is initialized in the Activity but not in the ListAdapter..., pass a reference to the activiy variable if you wanna use that one, or make it singleton, an obtain the instance in the ListAdapter

Comment: But I already initialized dbHelper from the activity that sets the ExpandableListAdapter to the ExpandableListView: In fn onCreate of that activity, I have 'dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);' and 'dbHelper.open()' Do I have to initialize it again? Also, one question that arises then is, since the constructor DbHelper() calls a Database() constructor to create all the database tables, will duplicate tables be created when I call DbHelper() again to initialize the variable?

Comment: The ListAdapter can't know that the dbHelper attribute is the same dbHelper of the Activity... each class is encapsulated and can't know the other class attibutes..., you should pass the dbHelper to the ListAdapter, using a context, or using a method like DbHelper getInstance(){ if(dbHelper == null){dbHelper = new DbHelper();} return dbHelper;} which return the same instance, then you can use the same DB instance in different places